# calculating the mean using input in Python?

Tags: list, input, import, average, mean

```
Want to make this code with input () of a list.

from statistics import mean
def Average(lst):
    return mean(lst)

lst = [15, 9, 55, 41, 35, 20, 62, 49]
average = Average(lst)

print("Average of the list =", round(average, 2))
```

I have tried to replace the lst part with input and int as well as empty list.

making statistics for mean with function and input as well as import.

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be make a loop and input the user to enter a number. If the user wants to finish the inputting, he/she just hits Enter:

```py
from statistics import mean


def Average(lst):
    return mean(lst)


lst = []
while True:
    num = input("Please input a number (just Enter to finish input): ")
    if num.strip() == "":
        break
    lst.append(int(num))

average = Average(lst)
print("Average of the list =", round(average, 2))
```

Prints (for example):

```
Please input a number (just Enter to finish input): 10
Please input a number (just Enter to finish input): 20
Please input a number (just Enter to finish input): 30
Please input a number (just Enter to finish input): 
Average of the list = 20
```

Comment: Please upvote and mark the answer as the accepted response, so people looking after this question will know this was helpful as well as keeping the motivation of people to answer